# Why must I wait 5s after deleting my own comment to perform any other comment actions?

Tags: bug, feature-request, status-bydesign, comment, rate-limiting

If I delete a comment of mine, and then try to upvote a following comment, the upvote is rejected, with the message "You may only submit a comment vote every 5 seconds":

[image: screengrab of annoying message]

Apparently, my deletion of my own comment was considered a "comment vote".

Similarly, I have to wait five seconds between deleting my own comment and flagging as obsolete a following comment that refers to it.

I understand the rationale for enforcing a delay after comment upvoting or comment flagging, but I do not understand the delay after I delete my own comment. It seems more like an artifact of implementation than a policy.  If so, it is a bug that should be fixed.

Comment: It's to prevent those with *very* fast fingers from implementing a [DoS attack](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Denial-of-service_attack).

Comment: On Meta.SO: [Deleting a comment (mine) shouldn't count as a comment vote](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/14185) is [meta-tag:status-bydesign], so currently there is little prospect of a change.

Comment: Links: (**1**) [The complete rate-limiting guide](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/164899/the-complete-rate-limiting-guide), (**2**) [Do not rate-limit deletion of my own comments](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/174121/do-not-rate-limit-deletion-of-my-own-comments), (**3**) [Rate Limiting and Velocity Checking](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2009/02/rate-limiting-and-velocity-checking.html) and (**4**) [Designing for evil](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2008/05/designing-for-evil.html).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This is by design. All comment actions are rate-limited, and actions that fall under the rate-limit are rejected immediately, before the system checks anything else (for example, what action you are trying to perform, or whether the comment has been deleted). This is to prevent any clever Denial of Service attacks, and is discussed in StackExchange [podcast #65](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2009/08/podcast-65/). Changing this behavior has been discussed before on Meta.SO as indicated in the comments, as well as [here](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3450/five-minute-limit-message-should-take-precedence-over-five-second-limit-message) on meta.math. In both cases the SE devs have indicated that they are unlikely to change this behavior.